# php preg_match accept alnum and chinese characters

Tags: php, html, regex

I would like my preg_match syntax to

- Accept Letters and numbers (numbers alone is not allowed)
- Disallow Spaces
- Disallow special characters (e.g !@#$%^&.,)
- Minimum of 3 chars to 12.
- Allow chinese characters (can be all alone, or with letters or numbers, or both.)

This was my attempted code, but i seemed to fail my goal

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]{3,12}+$/', $nickname)) {
//accepted
}
else {
//denied
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would use the `u` modifier along with [an unicode character class](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) `\p{Han}`. Now the question is, what kind of letters do you accept?  Is `é` valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like below. `^(?!\d+$)` won't allow the strings which contain only numbers.

```
if(preg_match('~^(?!\d+$)[a-zA-Z0-9\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]{3,12}+$~u', $nickname)) {
//accepted
}
else {
//denied
}
```